# How to put a vertical line between two divs if one has a fixed height and the other a variable height including zero height

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am working in asp.net webforms. I have two divs - left and right.The left div has a fixed height of 500px and will always have contents such as textboxes. The right div may or may not contain a gridview. If it contains, the gridview can have a variable height depending upon the number of row. I have  the following style in the left div: border-right: 1px solid grey; This puts a vertical line in between these two divs. It looks nice as long as the right div is of the same size as the left div. However when the gridview grows longer than 500px, this line doesn't look good. Unfortunately I can't put similar border-left on the right div since it may or may not have contents Essentially I want to have a border between these two divs which grows as per the right div and if the right div doesn't have any content then covers the left div.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set the right border for the left hand side div.

You can hook to resize of the second div and give them classes that set their border if the second div is taller than the first one:

```js
$(function() {
   $('#logger').bind('resize', function(e) {
   var prevHeight = $('#test').height();
  var curHeight = $('#logger').height();            
  if (curHeight > prevHeight) {
    console.log('greater');
    $('#logger').addClass('border-left');
    $('#test').removeClass('border-right','');
  }else {
    $('#logger').removeClass('border-left');
    $('#test').addClass('border-right');
  }  
});
});



function changeHeight() {
  $('#logger').height($('#logger').height() + 100);
  $('#logger').trigger('resize');
  
  
}
```

```css
#test, #logger {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left
}

#test {  
  height: 100px;
}

.border-left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="border-right">
  test
</div>
<div id="logger">
  test 2
</div>

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="changeHeight()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a second div within that div for border as follows:

CSS

```
.border-right{
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 500px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="left">
  <div class="border-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: My current code works. I want it to grow if the right div becomes taller

Comment: What if you would try to use table as use columns instead of divs, then border of left column would carry on depending on how big right column would be